# Even Degree Bridge Proof

Tags: graph-theory

Prove that every connected graph all of whose vertices have even degrees contains no bridges.

Any help/hints are greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

Suppose there's a bridge. Removing the bridge creates two connected components. Each of these components have precisely one odd vertex. Now why is that a contradiction?

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** Think about Eulerian circuits.